# Connect ASP.Net application from web to my sql database on my computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am creating two applications: An ASP.Net application and a C# application. I used SQL Server as the database. My ASP.Net application should connect to the internet but the database should only be on my computer. I used connectionString to connect my two applications in just one database (SQL). Is there a way to connect my ASP.Net application from the web to my SQL database on my computer?

I've read lots of tutorial but I can't find the solution.

Comment: You just setup correctly the web.config to connect to the remote sql server. Also you can connect the two computers with tunneling and make the same connection again using the web.config.

Comment: can you tcping your computer (the host of SQLserver) from your Asp.net server?

Comment: Is there a way to connect my application from internet(ASP.net project) to a sql database in my computer? Internet and MyComputer connection.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary SQL Server is local to to the Web application (it's either located on the same LAN or sometimes even on the same machine).

Technically it is possible to connect an ASP.NET application to a remote SQL server, but it is not recommended, you can open a can of worms there (problems with firewalls, ports, performance etc.)

Comment: Thanks. but what i am doing is not only for LAN connection.. it is a connection between the internet and my computer. Help me please. I am newbie here. My ASP.Net should be running on the internet(Webhosting) then it should connect to the sql database on my computer.

Comment: Any particular reason you cannot use SQL Sever on the host? Many hosts provide SQL Server hosting as well. Otherwise both you and the host (which is highly unlikely) will have to open port 1433 on respective firewalls to allow direct communication. If this happens you can use connectionString, specfiying public IP of your computer as a server name. But in this case if IP of your computer is not static - you will be in trouble when it's dynamically changed by ISP. There're ways around it (Dynamic DNS etc.) but it's not worth it.

Comment: Another possible solution is to use SQL Server Compact in you ASP.NET application. This way you can deploy it with your application (see more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx)

Comment: I have two application.. one is a c# application that is only running on my computer.. it is also connected to my SQL Server that's why i can't depploy my ASP.net with the SQL. I have only one database for both application. but the ASP.Net application should be deploy on web.

Comment: If i will have a static IP address.. how can i use this on my connection string? how i can insert the ip address on my connection string?

Comment: You would use it in `server=[server name]` part of your connection string, e.g. `server=43.23.13.111`. But, again, you have to make sure that host's and your firewalls allow communication on SQL Server port (default 1433)

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for that:

1. Make sure you have a static IP address assigned by the ISP.
2. Make sure that you assign a static IP address in your computer.
3. Now, use "Port Forwarding" technique. Configure your router to forward the packets from port 1433 going to your computer.
4. The next thing you do is you configure or modify your web.config (ASP.NET file) that is deployed outside your network (in a hosting company) and make sure that the datasource of your connectionString looks something like this: connectionString="data source=214.23.12.21 (where 214.23.12.21 is the static public IP assigned to you by your ISP).